# CoreGraphics Function Blocking

Tags: c, core-graphics

I'm am planning to use CoreGraphics for its low-level functionality, so I wrote up a small snippet that I expected to work:

```
#include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

int main() {
  double rot = CGDisplayRotation(0);
  printf("Rotation %f\n", rot);
  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the call `CGDisplayRotation` blocks. When I tried writing a similar snippet in XCode though, it works just fine but I will not be able to use XCode for unrelated reasons. Am I compiling incorrectly? Could this be a permission issue?

I compiled with `clang -Wall -framework CoreGraphics core.c -o core.o`